# Order of nontrivial elements is 2 implies Abelian group

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups, motivation

If the order of all nontrivial elements in a group is 2, then the group is Abelian. I know of a proof that is just from calculations (see below). I'm wondering if there is any **theory or motivation** behind this fact. Perhaps to do with commutators?

---

Proof: $a \cdot b = (b \cdot b)  \cdot (a \cdot b) \cdot (a \cdot a) = b \cdot (b \cdot a) \cdot (b\cdot a) \cdot a = b \cdot a$.

Comment: It's kind of an odd thing isn't it. Maybe it could help you to understand how counterexamples exist for groups of exponent p > 2 and how these counterexamples fail when p becomes 2.

Comment: HI Calvin.  I do not understand your proof.  Are a and b supposed to be arbitrary elements in a group having the property that every (non-identity) element has order 2?  I understand the second equation follows from associativity but I do not understand anything else in your proof.

Comment: @GeoffreyCritzer Yes. $a^2 = b^2 = 1$. So $ab = a^2 * ab * b^2$.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Every element of a group has order $2$. Why, intuitively, is it abelian?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/814374/every-element-of-a-group-has-order-2-why-intuitively-is-it-abelian)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As every non-identity element has order two, $a^{-1} = a$ for any element of the group. Therefore $$[a, b] = aba^{-1}b^{-1} = abab = (ab)^2 = e.$$ Hence the group is abelian. Is this too calculationy?

Comment: Haha thanks! I knew I was missing something as obvious as that. I thought the commutator subgroup was tricky, but completely forget that I could just do that ...

Comment: As a learner, the following idea helps me: commutator subgroup is exactly what you want to force to be identity in order to make a group abelian.

For example, we see that if $N \unlhd G$. Then $G/N$ is abelian if and only if $G' \subseteq N$.

Comment: Plus, I agree that learning/using more vocabulary (e.g. "commutator subgroups") is difficult. However, when you deal with more difficult problems, extra vocabulary makes those tedious steps "obvious." A typical example is as follows: let $H \leqslant G$. We see that $N_{G}(H) = \{g \in G : H^{g} = H\}$ is a subgroup, just by looking at it as a stabilizer subgroup of conjugation action of $G$ on $H$.

Answer (score 37):

Taking inverses reverses the order of multiplication, so if every element is its own inverse multiplication must be commutative.

Comment: That is a nice way of saying it.

Comment: Wow, this is really nice.

Answer (score 5):

$[a,b]=1$ for all $a,b\in G$ if and only if $G$ is abelian.  You proved that $[a,b]=a^{-1}b^{-1}ab=1$ above - this is the connection to commutators.

I don't know of any strong motivation behind this fact aside from, I guess, knowing that any nonabelian group must have an element of order $>2$.  I think that it is just a standard exercise.

It may interest you motivationally to prove that $G/H$ is abelian *if and only if* $G'\leqslant H$ (if $H \unlhd G$).

Comment: Any hints on how to show that any non-abelian group has an element of order >2? If $ab\neq ba$, we could still have $abab=e$. Am thinking of $S_3$ with $r, f$.

Comment: @CalvinLin Try the contrapositive.

Answer (score 1):

The idea of this approach is to work with a class of very small, finite, subgroups $H$ of $G$ in which we can prove commutativity. The reason for this is to be able to use the results like Cauchy's theorem and Lagrange's theorem.

Consider the subgroup $H$ generated by two distinct, nonidentity elements $a,b$ in the given group. The group $H$ consists of strings of instances of $a$ and $b$. By induction on the length of a string, one can show that any string of length 4 or longer is equal to a string of length 3 or shorter.

Using this fact we can list the seven possible elements of $H$:
$$1,a,b,ab,ba,aba,bab.$$ By (the contrapositive of) Cauchy's Theorem, the only prime divisor of $|H|$ is 2. This implies the order of $H$ is either $1$, $2$, or $4$.

If $|H|=1$ or $2$, then either $a$ or $b$ is the identity, a contradiction.
Hence $|H|$ has four elements. The subgroup generated by $a$ has order 2; its index in $H$ is 2, so it is a normal subgroup. Thus, the left coset $\{b,ba\}$ is the same as the right coset$\{b,ab\}$, and as a result $ab=ba$.

Comment: After establishing $|H|=4$ we could have also said $H$ is a p-group so it has nontrivial center, and $H/Z(H)$ is cyclic, so $H$ is abelian.

Answer (score 1):

> **Lemma:** Let $G$ be a group. Let $g\in G\setminus \{e\}$. Then $|g|=2$ if and only if $g=g^{-1}.$

*Proof:* Suppose $|g|=2$. Then $g^2=e$, so

$$\begin{align}
g&=ge\\
&=g(gg^{-1})\\
&=g^2g^{-1}\\
&=eg^{-1}\\
&=g^{-1}.
\end{align}$$

Now suppose $g=g^{-1}$. Then $g^2=gg=gg^{-1}=e$. But $g\neq e$. Hence $|g|=2.$ $\square$

> **Lemma:** Let $g,h$ be in a group $G$. Then $$(gh)^{-1}=h^{-1}g^{-1}.$$

*Proof:* We have that inverses are unique and $$(gh)(h^{-1}g^{-1})=geg^{-1}=gg^{-1}=e.\, \square $$

> **Theorem:** Suppose $a^2=e$ for all $a\in G$, where $G$ is a group. Then $G$ is abelian.

*Proof:* Let $g,h\in G$. Then

$$\begin{align}
gh&=(gh)^{-1}\\
&=h^{-1}g^{-1}\\
&=hg.
\end{align}$$

But $g,h\in G$ were arbitrary. Hence $G$ is abelian. $\square$

Comment: There is a typo in the proof of the first lemma, the order of g should be |g|=2.

Comment: Thank you, @Lazy_Butter :)