# Let $G$ be a group with 4 elements. Show that it is abelian.

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification, finite-groups

Hey so i tried this but i dont really know if its correct. I need some suggestions.

Let $G$ be $\{e,a,b,c\}$ Let's assume $G$ is not abelian.

This means there exist $a,b$ such that $ab\neq ba$.

We can choose 2 elements $a, b$ who are not inverse to each other.

We know that $(ab≠b \land ab≠e \land ab≠a) \implies ab=c$; we also know that $(ba≠b \land ba≠e \land ba≠a \land ab≠ba) \implies ba=d$ which is a contradiction to our assumption that G had 4 elements.

Is this proof legit ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prove that every group of order $4$ is abelian](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/443642/prove-that-every-group-of-order-4-is-abelian)

Comment: Looks good! Only, you do not need to argue by contradiction, you will just have that $ab = c = ba$.

Comment: thanks everyone for your help <333

Answer (score 5):

Your proof is good, but it can be made more elegant. This is a matter of experience... keep practising!

> Let G be {e,a,b,c} Let's assume G is not abelian.
>
> This means there exist a,b such that ab≠ba.

It's strange to say "there exist $a,b$" when $a$ and $b$ are already explicit objects. Better wording would be, "there exist two elements, say $a$ and $b$, that do not commute." Alternatively, "without loss of generality, assume $ab \neq ba$."

> We can choose 2 elements a, b who are not inverse to each other.

Again it is strange to be "choosing" $a$ and $b$ at this point since we are already working with them. Better: "Note that $a$ and $b$ are not inverses of each other, for then $ab=ba=e$."

> We know that (ab≠b ^ ab≠e ^ ab≠a)-> ab=c;

You could write this more smoothly thus: "Since $ab \notin \{a,b,e\}$, it follows that $ab = c$."

> ... we also know that (ba≠b ^ ba≠e ^ ba≠a ^ ab≠ba) -> ba=d which is a contradiction to our assumption that G had 4 elements.

I understand what you mean here, but what exactly is $d$? If you really want to keep this $d$, it would be clearer to write, "$ba = d$ for some $d \notin G$, contradicting the closure of $G$". But this is more complex than necessary; avoid introducing new objects if you can. Instead, just appeal to symmetry: "By the same reasoning, we also have $ba = c$. But then $ab = ba$, a contradiction."

---

The revised proof:

> Let $G = \{e,a,b,c\}$. Let's assume $G$ is not abelian; without loss of generality, assume $ab \neq ba$. Note that $a$ and $b$ are not inverses of each other, for then $ab = ba = e$.
>
> Since $ab \notin \{a,b,e\}$, it follows that $ab=c$. By the same reasoning, $ba=c$. But then $ab=ba$, a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

If $a\in G$ has order 4. done, if not there exists $a\neq b$ of order 2 and $a\neq b^{-1}$. We have $ab\neq a$ otherwise $a^{-1}(ab)=1=b$, you also have $ab\neq b$. The group is $\{1,a,b,ab\}$, but $ba\neq a, ba\neq b$, so $ba=ab$.

Comment: The OP's proof is correct; The OP asked for feedback on *their* proof.  the OP did not ask for other proofs (and yours isn't really any different, anyway). The OP asked for feedback on *their* proof, and you never addressed that in your answer!

Answer (score 0):

The order of each element divides the order of the group. If there is an element of order $4$, then $G$ is cyclic and trivially abelian.

If there is no element of order $4$, then every (non-identity) element has order $2$. Can you show the following general proposition?

> **Lemma:** If every element of a group $G$ has order $2$, then $G$ is abelian.

Comment: The OP's proof is correct; the OP did not ask for other proofs (and yours isn't really any different, anyway). The OP asked for feedback on *their* proof. And you never answered that.

Answer (score 0):

There are two cases.

1. If $G$ is cyclic, then $G$ is obviously commutative.
2. If $G$ is not cyclic, then every non-trivial element has order $2$. Let then $e \ne x \in G$: we then have the subgroup $\{ e, x \}$. Pick now $y \in G \setminus \{ e, x \}$, therefore so far we have the elements $\{ e, x, y \}$. What about the elements $xy$ and $yx$? Well, since $G$ has only $4$ elements, it follows that some two of $\{ e, x, y, xy, yx \}$ must be equal. Since $x, y \ne e$, the only possibility is $xy = yx$, which means commutativity.

Comment: The OP's proof is correct; the OP did not ask for other proofs (and yours isn't really any different, anyway). Anyway, the OP asked for feedback on *their* proof; and  to that you failed to respond.

Comment: @amWhy: Your remark is perfectly true. It is equally true, though, that while correct, the OP's proof is not very elegant (according to my taste, at least). He has now three more elegant proofs to choose from, plus those in the post linked to by Babak S.

Comment: The point is, you failed in failing to give the OP feedback on his/her post.  If you had, and then went on to offer suggestions on simplifying the post, all the more power to you.  How would you feel if you were an OP, andworked hard on a proof, posting it in order to check if your proof is correct, and get feedback (about your proof), only to be given other proofs?  Those offered proofs may be more sophisticated, but wouldn't you also want a direct answer regarding *your* proof?