# A group of order $16$ with a normal subgroup of order $4$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

This is an exercise assigned by my prof, for which I need some help. If $G$ is a group of order $16$ with a normal subgroup $N$ of order $4$, why for every $a, b \in G$ we have that $ab=ban$ for some $n \in N$ ?

The order of the quotient is $4$, so is abelian, then if $a, b \in G$ we have that $aNbN=bNaN$ and then?

Comment: Hint:  you can say something pretty definite about the quotient.

Comment: The order of the quotient is four.

Comment: And therefore must be....

Comment: Hint: every group of order $4$ is abelian. But please show some effort of your own, otherwise the community will close this post.

Comment: mybe abelian, no?

Comment: If $N$ is normal, then $aN=Na$ for every $a$.

Comment: so  $abN=baN$ and for every $n_1, n_2 \in N$ we have $abn_1=ban_2$ thus $ab=ban_2n_1^{-1}$?

Comment: Almost, take $n_2$ the element corresponding to $n_1=e$.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

By Lagrange's Theorem, $|G/N|=|G|/|N|=16/4=4$. [Every group of order four is abelian.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/443642/104041) Therefore,

$$\begin{align}
(ab)N&=(aN)(bN)\\
&=(bN)(aN)\\
&=(ba)N
\end{align}$$

for all $a,b\in G$. But this means $ab=(ab)e\in (ab)N=(ba)N$ (because $e\in N$ since $N\unlhd G$), which implies there exists an $n\in N$ with $ab=ban$.