# Every element of a group has order $2$. Why, intuitively, is it abelian?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

What is the intuition behind the fact that if every element in a group is of order $2$, we have that the group is abelian? I can prove it, but I do not know the intuition behind it.

Comment: Perhaps that there are simply not enough "degrees of freedom" to be nonabelian? You just can't get any nonabelian relations once you have that $aabb=abab=e$ for all$a,b$.

Comment: What is the meaning of the degree of freedom here? How can I categorize some group is abelian by this degree of freedom?

Comment: I mean the availability of relations on the group elements. That is, equations the group elements satisfy. You immediately get the relation I provided above, and it instantly rules out any nonabelian relation.

Comment: I don't think there's much of an intuition. I don't see how an intuitive explanation could distinguish $2$ from $3$ without just going through the proof, but the conclusion is false with $2$ replaced by $3$.

Comment: A small comment: no group has the property that its every element has order $2$, since the identity always has order $1$.

Comment: @user: it's common to see people say "order $n$" when they mean "$n$-torsion," e.g. order dividing $n$. I think the meaning is clear.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think it is a special case of a general case which is;

**Lemma** :if $f:G\to G$ by $f(x)=x^{-1}$ is a homomorphism if and only if $G$ is abelian.

Now think that you have this lemma and you are looking for a case which can happen. The most natural idea is setting; $x=x^{-1}$ for all $x$ i.e $x^2=e$ then $f$ becomes identity map which is a homomorphism so we should have an abelian group.

Now, you can ask that what is the intuation of the lemma ? It is also natural since every element has uniqe inverse then the map is a bijection and it is natural to ask when this bijection is a homomorphism.

Comment: I think its cool that if the inversion function $G \rightarrow G$ is a homomorphism, then (by your lemma) so too is the law of composition $G^2 \rightarrow G.$

Answer (score 6):

I think of it like this: If $a,b$ are in the group, then $ab$ is in the group and of order 2 by assumption... but this means

$$ (ab)^2=abab=e \implies ab=ba $$

Comment: Nice answer. A small comment: it would be more correct to say that $ab$ is of order *at most* $2$ with respect to the divisibility order.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not exactly sure what you're looking for in an intuitive explanation, so I'll just explain how I look at it. Hopefully it will be helpful for you as well.

The statement that every element has order 2 is equivalent to the statement that every element is its own inverse. If you are comfortable with inverses being unique, then commutativity is simply the observation that $abba$ is the identity for any $a$ and $b$ in the group, because it shows that $ba$ is the inverse of $ab$. Does this make it any more clear?

Edit: Mesel's answer inspired me to think on this a little more. In any group you have a composition operation and inverses. So we can take two elements of the group $a$ and $b$ (with inverses $a^{-1}$ and $b^{-1}$) and combine them to get $ab$. A natural question to ask is what the inverse of this new element $ab$ is, in terms of the four elements we started with. It's not hard to see that it is $b^{-1}a^{-1}$.

Now we have this interesting relation $(ab)^{-1}=b^{-1}a^{-1}$ in which the elements are flipped. This suggests that there might be some connection between inversion and commutativity. The lemma that mesel mentioned describes that connection precisely (and as a bonus is easy to prove).

Answer (score 0):

Clarifying Jeb's answer a little:

$(ab)^2 = e\\
abab = e$

Multiply by $a$ on the left:

$aabab = a\\
(aa)bab = a\\
bab = a$

Multiply by $b$ on the right:

$babb = ab\\
ba(bb) = ab\\
ba = ab$