# I tried to find every non-abelian group of order 8. Please help me find my error.

Tags: group-theory

I wanted to find all non-abelian groups of order 8 up to isomorphism, but I ran into a contradiction and I can't find the error in my reasoning. My reasoning was as follows:

Since the groups we're after are non-abelian 2-groups, their center is neither trivial nor the whole group. So let's do a case distinction on the order of the center being either 2 or 4.

If the center $Z/(G)$ has order 4, then the quotient group $G/Z(G)$ has order 2 and is therefore cyclic. We now invoke the [following theorem](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Quotient_of_Group_by_Center_Cyclic_implies_Abelian) to reach a contradiction on G being non-abelian.

So the center has order 2 and the quotient group $G/Z(G)$ has order 4. The Klein four-group is the only non-cyclic group of order 4 (which is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$), so it holds that $G/Z(G) \cong G/\mathbb{Z}_2 \cong \mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$. But now all my elements have order 2, right? [Which would mean the group is abelian again](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/275544/order-of-nontrivial-elements-is-2-implies-abelian-group).

[The actual solutions](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Groups_of_Order_8) are the dihedral and and the dicyclic group and even though I understand that proof, I simply cannot find the error in my proof, mainly because I'm new to group theory. So any help is deeply appreciated.

Comment: You are saying that the quotient has all elements order 2 and so does the "denominator," therefore so does $G$.  If you try to prove this statement on its own, you will see where it goes wrong.

Comment: But since all elements be written in the form $ab$, where $a \in \mathbb{Z}_2$ and $b \in \mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$, if thought that if I multiply an element with itself, I get with the commutativity of the center that $abab = aabb = ee = e$.

Comment: But $b$ is not an element of $\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2$. It’s an element of $G$ that **maps** to an element of $\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2$. That means that $b^2$ lies in the kernel of the map... but it need not be trivial. It could be equal that $b^2=a$.

Comment: That's possible?? I never knew! Thank you very much!

Comment: @LionCoder  I think you're assuming that the quotient splits (the product is direct and not semi- or something weaker), which it need not.  This is the same as Arturo's comment.

Comment: Well I did but not intentionally. Now that you made me aware of this property, I understand what is happening.

Comment: No one has said it, but your work up to that point was right on.

Comment: It helps to know what the other nonabelian group of order eight *is*. Do you?

Comment: OP said as much in the question.