# if a+a = e, and G is a group, then G is abelian.

Tags: group-theory

Let $(G,+)$ be a Group.
I want to show that if $a+a=e$ (e being the neutral element) is true for all $a \in G$ then the Group G is abelian.

My first thought is that $a$ must be zero. Sadly I don't have any ideas how to start on this problem. Any tips are welcome.

I know that abelian is just another word for commutative. So when we have $a+b$ then it must be the same as $b+a$ or $a\cdot b =b \cdot a$.

Any tips?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Order of nontrivial elements is 2 implies Abelian group](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/275544/order-of-nontrivial-elements-is-2-implies-abelian-group)

Comment: Kind of. Thomas perfectly explained it in the chat. Basically: We've shown that for (a+b) the inverse is (b+a) we've found two expressions which are both inverse. Since the inverse element is unqiue (group axioms) we can conclude (a+b)=(b+a), therefore commutative/abelian.

Comment: An alternative which may be either be more direct or much harder to follow depending on the reader is $$(a+b) + (a+b) = e\\(a+b)+a+(b+b)=e+b\\(a+b)+a+e=b\\(a+b)+a=b\\(a+b)+a+a=b+a\\(a+b)+e=b+a\\a+b=b+a$$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $(a+b) + (b+a) = a+ b+b+a = a+e+a = a+a = e$

(This is a hint, as you have asked for, but only one steps remains to show what you want).

Comment: I guess the last step is to show that (a+b)=(b+a)? I hope this isn't a very stupid question :(

Comment: @Lisa The calculation shows that $b+a$ is the inverse of $a+b$. What do you know about the inverse?

Comment: I know that for $+$ the Inverse of an element $a$ is $-a$. For $\cdot$ the inverse of $a$ is $a^{-1}$

Comment: You know a bit more - first, you make an assumption about the inverse in your question. Then you have just, correctly, written "the" inverse. (As opposed to "some" inverse).

Comment: Oh, maybe since because we know that for $a$ the inverse is $-a$ and with how you've shown that $b+a$ is the inverse of $a+b$ in this case we can conclude $a+b -(b+a) =0$?

Comment: By assumption, the inverse of any $a\in G$ is $a$. So the inverse of $a+b$ is $a+b$. My calculation shows that also $b+a$ is inverse to $a+b$. What do you now need to finish? Look at my previous comment.

Comment: We assumed the inverse of $a$ being $a$ and showed that this isn't the case and therefore we conclude that $G$ must be abelian?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133330/discussion-between-thomas-and-lisa).