# If G is a group and $a^2=e$, then G is abelian.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification, abelian-groups

My Proof:

$$x=x$$
$$ex=xe$$
$$y^2x=xy^2$$
$$y^{-1}y^2x=xy^2y^{-1}$$
$$yx=xy$$

Is this right?
Thanks!

Comment: In the line before the last, you multiplied by $y^{-1}$ on the left on one side and on the right on the other side.

Comment: [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/275544/order-of-nontrivial-elements-is-2-implies-abelian-group) is a duplicate for the underlying question.

Comment: $y^2x=xy^2\Rightarrow y^{-1}y^2x=xy^2y^{-1}$ is a mistake of algebra.

Comment: This is not a "check-my-proof" site. You should follow the instructions in the `solution-verification` tag (which was proper for this post and I added): ""Is my proof correct?" is off topic (too broad, missing context). Instead, the question must identify precisely which step in the proof is in doubt, and why so. "  Your post is either inappropriate, or a duplicate.

Comment: Do you mean $a^2=e$ for all $a\in G?$

Comment: $ab=(ab)^{-1}=b^{-1}a^{-1}=ba$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Yes

Comment: If that's what you mean, Arthr, then that's what you should write. But it's a moot point, since apparently the question's a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

$x^2=1$ imply $x=x^{-1}$

So $xy=x^{-1}y^{-1}=(yx)^{-1}=yx$

Comment: This question seems not to meet the standards for the site. Instead of answering it, it would be better to look for a good duplicate target, or help the user by posting comments suggesting improvements. Please also read the [meta announcement](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/) regarding quality standards.